# WCF Service reference type property to be modified before serialization

Tags: c#, wcf, synchronization

Let's say that we have following Service, with two operation contracts.

```C#
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IServiceCallback))]
public interface IService : IDisposable
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(ServiceProperty))]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceMethodFaultException))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(object[]))]
    ServiceProperty GetServicePropertyAbc();

    [OperationContract]
    void ModifyServicePropertyAbc();
}
```

And the service that is implementing the IService:

```C#
public class ServiceBase : IService
{
   ServiceProperty abc;

   public ServiceProperty GetServicePropertyAbc()
    {
          //somelogic
          return abc;
    }

   public void ModifyServicePropertyAbc()
   {
    abc = new ServiceProperty();
    abc.SomeProperty = 100 * 100;
   }
}
```

And we have:

- "Client 1" that use the ServiceBase as a proxy
- "Client 2" that use the ServiceBase as a proxy

Service-host is the same for both of the clients.

And there's following scenario:

- **Step 1** GetServiceProperty() is being called by "Client 1" with success
- **Step 2** GetServiceProperty() returns abc;
- **Step 3** abc is being serialized to XML
- **Step 4** "Client 1" is getting the XML response

Is there possibility that that between **Step 2** and **Step 3** the "Client 2" could have modify the **ServiceProperty abc** with **ModifyServicePropertyAbc()** so the "Client 1" would have modified "abc"??

Let's assume that there's logic in **GetServicePropertyAbc()** method which makes lock on **abc** (our code is 100% thread safe but we're afraid what when we're going out of the GetServiceProperty() scope).

I'm just wondering if there's possibility that **ServiceProperty abc** can be modified between Step 2 and Step 3 or WCF guarantess that It won't be modified??

**ServiceProperty** is a reference type and it is really complex (cannot be replaced with the value type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely scenario is that since you have on your service contract that each time you make a call you are creating a new instance of your service. The [IsInitiating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isinitiating?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute defaults to true for session based services so each time you call you start with a new instance.

```
SessionMode = SessionMode.Required
```